# Camera crashes after first image upload

Tags: java, android, android-intent, out-of-memory, android-camera-intent

I'm trying to create an app that will take a photo and the upload the photo to my server. So far so good. The problem is when I want to try to take another photo AFTER uploading the first one. It looks like an OutOfMemory error but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

```
public class HomePage extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private static final int TAKE_PICTURE = 0;
    private Uri mUri;
    private Bitmap mPhoto;

    TextView welcomeText;
    String username;

    // Alert Dialog Manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    // Session Manager Class
    SessionManagement session;

    // Button Logout
    Button btnLogout;

    // Photo File
    File photoFile;
 @Override

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

     // Session class instance
     session = new SessionManagement(getApplicationContext());

     // Check that user is logged in
     session.checkLogin();
     // get user data from session
     HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
     // username
     username = user.get(SessionManagement.KEY_USERNAME);

     welcomeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcometext);

     ((Button) findViewById(R.id.snap)).setOnClickListener(this);
     ((Button) findViewById(R.id.rotate)).setOnClickListener(this);
     ((Button) findViewById(R.id.upload)).setOnClickListener(this);

     // Button logout
     ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout)).setOnClickListener(this);

     welcomeText.setText("Hello, " + username);


 }


@Override
```

This is where I initiated my buttons. R.id.snap is where the photo is taken and then I upload with the button R.id.upload. Ignore the R.id.rotate.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId()== R.id.snap) {
        Intent i = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        photoFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), username + ".jpg");

        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
        mUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
        startActivityForResult(i, TAKE_PICTURE);
    } 
    else if(v.getId() == R.id.rotate) 
    {
        if (mPhoto!=null) {
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
       matrix.postRotate(90);
       mPhoto = Bitmap.createBitmap(mPhoto , 0, 0, mPhoto.getWidth(), mPhoto.getHeight(), matrix, true);
       ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo_holder)).setImageBitmap(mPhoto);

           }

    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.upload)
    {
        try {
            welcomeText.setText("Uploading image");
            executeMultipartPost();
            //welcomeText.setText("Upload Complete");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            welcomeText.setText("Upload Failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnLogout)
    {
        session.logoutUser();
    }

}

@Override

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   switch (requestCode) {
   case TAKE_PICTURE:
       if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
           getContentResolver().notifyChange(mUri, null);
           ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
           try {
               mPhoto = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, mUri);
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo_holder)).setImageBitmap(mPhoto);
           } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
         }
   }

}
```

And this is where the file upload occurs.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void executeMultipartPost() throws Exception {
    try {

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
            "http://www.neurobomber.com/cfc/upload_nologin.php?method=post");

    ImageView jpgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo_holder);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
    jpgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    FileBody bin = new FileBody(photoFile);
    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
            HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    //Adding the file and username to be sent to the server
    reqEntity.addPart("userfile", bin);
    reqEntity.addPart("username",new StringBody(username));
    postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream webs = entity.getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webs, "iso-8859-1"),8);
    String sResponse;
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

    while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        s = s.append(sResponse);
    }
    welcomeText.setText(s);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle exception here
    //infotext.setText("Uploading image");
    Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
}
}
}
```

Here's my log output after it crashes if that helps at all:

```
07-16 01:36:27.236: I/[POST_RESELECT](3783): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$START@40105c38,-1,0,-1,0)
07-16 01:36:27.236: I/[POST_RESELECT](3783): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@4010fa20,-1,0,-1,0)
07-16 01:36:27.236: I/[POST_RESELECT](3783): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$START@40105c38,-1,0,-1,0)
07-16 01:36:27.236: I/[POST_RESELECT](3783): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@4010fa20,-1,0,-1,0)
07-16 01:36:27.256: I/[POST_RESELECT](3783): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$START@40105c38,-1,0,-1,0)
07-16 01:36:27.256: I/[POST_RESELECT](3783): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@4010fa20,-1,0,-1,0)
07-16 01:36:27.256: I/[POST_RESELECT](3783): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$START@40105c38,-1,0,-1,0)
07-16 01:36:27.256: I/[POST_RESELECT](3783): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@4010fa20,-1,0,-1,0)
07-16 01:36:27.256: I/[POST_RESELECT](3783): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$START@40105c38,-1,0,-1,0)
07-16 01:36:27.256: I/[POST_RESELECT](3783): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@4010fa20,-1,0,-1,0)
07-16 01:36:36.045: D/dalvikvm(3783): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 127K, 48% free 2833K/5447K, external 0K/0K, paused 41ms
07-16 01:36:37.607: D/dalvikvm(3783): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 53K, 49% free 2788K/5447K, external 12444K/14492K, paused 23ms
07-16 01:36:38.157: D/dalvikvm(3783): DexOpt: couldn't find static field
07-16 01:36:38.157: W/dalvikvm(3783): VFY: unable to resolve static field 3345 (INSTANCE) in Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueParser;
07-16 01:36:38.157: D/dalvikvm(3783): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x001b
07-16 01:36:38.167: D/dalvikvm(3783): VFY: dead code 0x001d-0043 in Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;.parse (Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;
07-16 01:36:38.167: D/dalvikvm(3783): DexOpt: couldn't find static field
07-16 01:36:38.167: W/dalvikvm(3783): VFY: unable to resolve static field 3339 (INSTANCE) in Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueFormatter;
07-16 01:36:38.167: D/dalvikvm(3783): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0015
07-16 01:36:38.167: D/dalvikvm(3783): VFY: dead code 0x0017-001c in Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;.toString ()Ljava/lang/String;
07-16 01:36:54.453: D/dalvikvm(3783): GC_CONCURRENT freed 91K, 46% free 3029K/5575K, external 24888K/26936K, paused 2ms+1ms
07-16 01:36:54.483: D/dalvikvm(3783): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 4K, 46% free 3025K/5575K, external 24888K/26936K, paused 31ms
07-16 01:36:54.493: E/dalvikvm-heap(3783): 12742656-byte external allocation too large for this process.
07-16 01:36:54.493: E/dalvikvm(3783): Out of memory: Heap Size=5575KB, Allocated=3025KB, Bitmap Size=24888KB, Limit=32768KB
07-16 01:36:54.493: E/dalvikvm(3783): Trim info: Footprint=5575KB, Allowed Footprint=5575KB, Trimmed=844KB
07-16 01:36:54.493: E/GraphicsJNI(3783): VM won't let us allocate 12742656 bytes
07-16 01:36:54.513: D/dalvikvm(3783): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 181K, 49% free 2843K/5575K, external 24888K/26936K, paused 19ms
07-16 01:36:54.513: D/skia(3783): --- decoder->decode returned false
07-16 01:36:54.513: D/AndroidRuntime(3783): Shutting down VM
07-16 01:36:54.513: W/dalvikvm(3783): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
07-16 01:36:54.523: E/AndroidRuntime(3783): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 01:36:54.523: E/AndroidRuntime(3783): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget(Heap Size=7367KB, Allocated=2843KB, Bitmap Size=24888KB)
07-16 01:36:54.523: E/AndroidRuntime(3783):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
07-16 01:36:54.523: E/AndroidRuntime(3783):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:690)
07-16 01:36:54.523: E/AndroidRuntime(3783):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:749)
07-16 01:36:54.523: E/AndroidRuntime(3783):     at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.getBitmap(MediaStore.java:560)
07-16 01:36:54.523: E/AndroidRuntime(3783):     at com.neurobomber.photothrice.HomePage.onActivityResult(HomePage.java:145)
07-16 01:36:54.523: E/AndroidRuntime(3783):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4010)
07-16 01:36:54.523: E/AndroidRuntime(3783):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2879)
07-16 01:36:54.523: E/AndroidRuntime(3783):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2925)
07-16 01:36:54.523: E/AndroidRuntime(3783):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:132)
07-16 01:36:54.523: E/AndroidRuntime(3783):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1063)
07-16 01:36:54.523: E/AndroidRuntime(3783):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-16 01:36:54.523: E/AndroidRuntime(3783):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
07-16 01:36:54.523: E/AndroidRuntime(3783):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
07-16 01:36:54.523: E/AndroidRuntime(3783):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 01:36:54.523: E/AndroidRuntime(3783):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-16 01:36:54.523: E/AndroidRuntime(3783):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-16 01:36:54.523: E/AndroidRuntime(3783):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-16 01:36:54.523: E/AndroidRuntime(3783):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-16 01:36:56.225: I/Process(3783): Sending signal. PID: 3783 SIG: 9
```

Comment: you can try to `recycle` your bitmap after you sent it.

Comment: Using that just causes my app to crash right after the upload :-(

Comment: So I found a few minor unrelated bugs and came to the conclusion that your suggestion worked! Thanks!

Comment: Cool! was not sure that would work, so I didn't put it as an answer. Apparently the reason why the Bitmap is not simply garbage collected is because it is in a special Video memory which contains only stuff to blit on the screen, and which requires to be explicitely cleaned, for some reason.